# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcade'" after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror, arcade

The script runs fine but compiled with pyinstaller throws an error in runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poples.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcade'
[5316] Failed to execute script 'poples' due to unhandled exception!

Arcade(latest version:2.6.15)  is installed on my python folder:
    C:\Users\Sarp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
as well as installed in my project virtual enviroment folder
```

What I did so far:

- Fresh start: delete venv folder and recreate new
- using pycharms requirement.txt, I reinstalled all the required packages again
- I run `pyi-makespec` inside my project folder:

  ```
  pyi-makespec --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico poples.py
  ```
- Edit the spec file line: `hiddenimports=[],` to `hiddenimports=['arcade'],` and `console=False` to `console=True` (to see runtime error)

  It looks like this:

  ```
  block_cipher = None

  a = Analysis(
      ['poples.py'],
      pathex=[],
      binaries=[],
      datas=[],
      hiddenimports=['arcade'],
      hookspath=[],
      hooksconfig={},
      runtime_hooks=[],
      excludes=[],
      win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
      win_private_assemblies=False,
      cipher=block_cipher,
      noarchive=False,
  )
  pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

  exe = EXE(
      pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='poples',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True,
      disable_windowed_traceback=False,
      argv_emulation=False,
      target_arch=None,
      codesign_identity=None,
      entitlements_file=None,
      icon='icon.ico',
  )
  ```
- run pyinstaller inside my project folder
  pyinstaller poples.spec
- run the script through command promt
- got an error

Comment: Did you look at this? https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/tutorials/bundling_with_pyinstaller/index.html

Comment: Thanks Grimmy, yes I had been and found no information about modulenotfound. An I did the hiddein imports thing as mentioned. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I always copy pyinstaller.exe to my project folder then run fron there. and it always works for my other projects.. But when I delete pyinstaller from this project folder and run it did the job. but still I don't know why this is the case. Maybe arcade don't like the pyinstaller in my project folder.